# How to implement voice command based navigation in Android

Tags: android, voice, voice-recognition

I have an application with sevaral screens. In each screen, there are several links. Suppose when the user say "settings", it should open the settings screen, and when the user say "select something" in the settings screen, it should select the respective one.

I have seen some tutorials using `RecognizerIntent` but the problem with that is that it will open "Speak Now" popup to listen to the voice command and it will trigger only when some event is fired. I would like to know whether it is possible or not, if possible how can implement it.

Comment: check this link
[Start activity based on voice command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11798337/how-to-voice-commands-into-an-android-application) It have a good tutorial on how to implement voice search.

Comment: What is your question? Do you want to avoid user clicking some button to start recognition?

Comment: yes...and also I would like to know whether is there possibility to not have a "Speak now" popup

Answer (score 1):

You could avoid "Speak now" popup by using [SpeechRecognizer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html) class but it demands more coding then using Intent. Because you want to start recognition when user start speaking you should use some [voice activity detection algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12552091/how-to-catch-voice-input-when-user-speaks/12554418#12554418) and after voice activity is detected you then call `startRecognition` method.